# What's the differences between out and int* c#

Tags: c#

As far as I read sending out keyword in c#, will change the parameter.
So what's the different between those two cases:

1. using out:

   ```
   helper(out param){...}

    func(){

    int param = 0;

    helper(out param)}
   ```
2. using pointer:

   ```
   helper(int* param){..}  

    func(){

    int param = 0;

    helper(&param)}
   ```

Are they same ? Tnx.

Comment: [Assuming C#] The pointer requires unsafe code and could lead to memory exceptions if used incorrectly. It also does not guarantee that the item pointed at is initialised by the call. The `out` parameter does not suffer from those issues. Also note that you must specify the type of the `out` parameter: `helper(out int param)`

Comment: furthermore you *must* assign a value to an `out` parameter befor returing. Otherwise you get a compiler error.

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors.

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn’t use pointers like in C/C++. Instead in C# you should use references (where `out` here is one variant).

Comment: If you can do it without using pointers, then avoid them for various reasons.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - my code is full of syntax errors, because my question is not really on this code but theoretically, thought thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two things are conceptually similar. The key difference here is:

- `int*` is an unmanaged pointer
- `ref int` is a managed pointer
- `out int` is really just `ref int` with some extra compiler guard rails around definite assignment

So: what is the difference between a managed and unmanaged pointer? The key differences:

- the GC can correctly track managed pointers
- which means you don't need to pin/fix some things before you can use them
- and therefore you don't need to use `unsafe`
- and it is more verifiable
- and more people understand the code

Conversely:

- you can store an unmanaged pointer in a field on a type (managed pointers can only be held on the stack)
- but if that unmanaged pointer talks to something that has moved/gone away: BOOM

So: in any scenario where you *can* use a managed pointer (`ref` or `out`), in place of an unamnaged pointer: you *should*. Honestly, very few C# developers fully understand the nuances of managed pointers, but even fewer fully understand the nuances of unamnaged pointers.

Comment: Note also that you cannot take a pointer to a managed type such as a `struct`. Pointers can only be used with primitive types.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou IIRC you can have an unmanaged pointer to a struct, but that struct cannot have references as fields internally (and for managed pointers to a value-type: it can have references internally if it wants)

Answer (score 3):

The use cases are not same as the keywords name suggests.

The out is a keyword in C# which is used for the passing the arguments to methods as a reference type. It is generally used when a method returns multiple values. The out parameter does not pass the property.

The pointer in C# which is used for the passing the arguments by a reference. Or we can say that if any changes made in this argument in the method will pointer reflect in that variable when the control return to the calling method.

Pointers are typically there to interop with C++ and aren't to be used in day to day C# coding. We can use ref type.

Comment: " as a reference type" - no: it passes a (managed) reference, but it can be to a value-type; pass-by-reference and reference-type are completely different concepts

Answer (score 3):

On the higher level of course there are differences related to how `unsafe` code is implemented, such that you can only take pointers to primitive types vs. with the `out` keyword any type can be specified as an argument.

But it is interesting to see how the two differ down in the lower level assembly code.

Consider the minimum skeleton code.

```
static class Program
{
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x;
        SetArg(out x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        int y;
        SetArg(&y);
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }

    static void SetArg(out int x)
    {
        x = 10;
    }

    static unsafe void SetArg(int* ptr)
    {
        *ptr = 10;
    }
}
```

and the resulting assembly code which is inlined

```
            SetArg(out x);
00007FFD4EB80890  int         3  
00007FFD4EB80891  sub         esp,28h  
00007FFD4EB80894  xor         eax,eax  
00007FFD4EB80896  mov         dword ptr [rsp+24h],eax  
            Console.WriteLine(x);
00007FFD4EB8089A  mov         ecx,0Ah                           ! case a)
00007FFD4EB8089F  call        00007FFDAA4E2890  

            int y;
            SetArg(&y);
00007FFD4EB808A4  lea         rcx,[rsp+24h]  
00007FFD4EB808A9  mov         dword ptr [rcx],0Ah               ! case b)
            Console.WriteLine(y);
00007FFD4EB808AF  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+24h]  
00007FFD4EB808B3  call        00007FFDAA4E2890  
00007FFD4EB808B8  nop  
00007FFD4EB808B9  add         rsp,28h  
00007FFD4EB808BD  ret
```

In the first case with the `out` statement, the value `10 = 0Ah` is written directly to a register `ecx` before being written to the console by the `Writeline()` function. This is super optimized as no memory is utilized in this operation. This is why it is **not** recommended to micro optimize your code, and just convey intent with the `ref/out` keywords and let the compiler do its job.

In the second case with the `int*` argument, the value `10 = 0Ah` is written to a memory address on the stack corresponding to the function argument and then loaded up to `ecx` from that address before calling `Writeline()`. Here the code is not only unsafe but also less optimized as the programmer forced the compiler to store the intermediate value in the stack before usage.

Note than an alternate definition of `SetArg()` is

```
    static unsafe void SetArg(int* ptr)
    {
        ptr[0] = 10;  // same as ptr* = 10
    }
```

but this highlights another potential problem. Buffer overrun, or out of bounds memory access, because if you had written

```
ptr[-1] = 10;
```

or anything else other than `ptr[0]` which is the intended memory location, then you have corrupted the process memory causing havok.